Cloning most of an Ubuntu system disk, except for one data partition
I want to clone a 4 TB Ubuntu system drive, except for one data partition, to a 2 TB drive. The clone should be bootable, so the GPT data, EFI partition and system partition need to function. This does not seem to be possible using the Clonezilla menus, even in expert mode.
The image below shows the partitions on the drive to clone. All partitions should be copied to the new bootable drive, except the last partition (shown as /dev/sdb3, labeled Data):

I have no desire to reinvent Clonezilla, or to do any unnecessary programming. The most desirable outcome would be to learn how to use an unmodified Clonezilla to accomplish the task.
Clonezilla has dozens of interesting utilities in clonezilla/sbin/ for managing Linux drives. I have not found any documentation on these utilities.
My detailed notes are online.
